# where to find 2d textures of earth

Tags: image, opengl, textures

google images is no good. Where are there some free 2d images of earth, preferably in raw format to make it easier to read into open gl texture, to use to map onto a 3d sphere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [Blue Marble](http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Features/BlueMarble/) which now has newer high res photos (up to 500 m/pixel). But what sort of resolution do you need?

Comment: i never did this before, so i have no idea how high i need the resolution to make it look good. I'm just doing a basic scene with earth mapped to sphere.

Comment: If you're showing the whole earth and not trying to zoom in, then it sounds like Blue Marble would fit your needs. You can try the different resolutions to see what looks best for your application.

Comment: I've used some of the free ones from this dude: http://planetpixelemporium.com/earth.html and he's got some of the other planets and moon as well.